# Socket.io used on a web server, wont relay the audio and video because of: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID client side

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, socket.io, webrtc

Im trying to create a multi streaming video and audio server, this is my sevrer.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);
    const https = require('https');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const app = express();
    // Create server
    var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem');
    var certificate = fs.readFileSync('server-crt.pem');
    var ca = fs.readFileSync("ca-crt.pem");

    var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: ca, transports: ['websocket']};

    // your express configuration here

    //var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
    var server = https.createServer(credentials,app).listen(3000, function(){
        console.log("Express server listening on port with https " + 3000);
    });


    // Array to map all clients connected in socket
    let connectedUsers = [];

    // Called whend a client start a socket connection
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // It's necessary to socket knows all clients connected
    connectedUsers.push(socket.id);

    // Emit to myself the other users connected array to start a connection with each them
    const otherUsers = connectedUsers.filter(socketId => socketId !== socket.id);
    socket.emit('other-users', otherUsers);
    console.log(socket.id);

    // Send Offer To Start Connection
    socket.on('offer', (socketId, description) => {
        socket.to(socketId).emit('offer', socket.id, description);
    });

    // Send Answer From Offer Request
    socket.on('answer', (socketId, description) => {
        socket.to(socketId).emit('answer', description);
    });

    // Send Signals to Establish the Communication Channel
    socket.on('candidate', (socketId, candidate) => {
        socket.to(socketId).emit('candidate', candidate);
    });

    // Remove client when socket is disconnected
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        connectedUsers = connectedUsers.filter(socketId => socketId !== socket.id);
    });
    });

    // Return Index HTML when access root route
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
    });

    // Start server in port 3000 or the port passed at "PORT" env variable
```

I created the certs for the server.js using this resource, from the top to the "Server" section:

```
    https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2
```

This is the client site.js:

```
    console.log('Main JS!');

    // Map All HTML Elements

    var messagesEl = document.querySelector('.messages');
    var messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
    var remoteVideo;
    $(document).ready(function () {


        var videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid');
        var localVideo = document.getElementById('local-video');
        var sendButton = document.getElementById('message-button');
        remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remote-video');

        // Open Camera To Capture Audio and Video
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
            .then(stream => {
                // Show My Video
                videoGrid.style.display = 'grid';
                localVideo.srcObject = stream;

                // Start a Peer Connection to Transmit Stream
                initConnection(stream);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));

        // Map the 'message-button' click
        sendButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // GET message from input
            const message = messageInput.value;
            // Clean input
            messageInput.value = '';
            // Log Message Like Sended
            logMessage(`Send: ${message}`);

            // GET the channel (can be local or remote)
            const channel = localChannel || remoteChannel;
            // Send message. The other client will receive this message in 'onmessage' function from channel
            channel.send(message);
        });
    })


    const logMessage = (message) => {
      const newMessage = document.createElement('div');
      newMessage.innerText = message;
      messagesEl.appendChild(newMessage);
    };

    var pcConfig = {
        'iceServers': [
            {
                'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
            }
        ]
    };
    const initConnection = (stream) => {
        const socket = io('https://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000');
      let localConnection;
      let remoteConnection;
      let localChannel;
      let remoteChannel;

      // Start a RTCPeerConnection to each client
      socket.on('other-users', (otherUsers) => {
        // Ignore when not exists other users connected
        if (!otherUsers || !otherUsers.length) return;

        const socketId = otherUsers[0];

        // Ininit peer connection
          localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(pcConfig);

        // Add all tracks from stream to peer connection
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => localConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

        // Send Candidtates to establish a channel communication to send stream and data
        localConnection.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
          candidate && socket.emit('candidate', socketId, candidate);
        };

        // Receive stream from remote client and add to remote video area
        localConnection.ontrack = ({ streams: [ stream ] }) => {
          remoteVideo.srcObject = stream;
        };

        // Start the channel to chat
        localChannel = localConnection.createDataChannel('chat_channel');

        // Function Called When Receive Message in Channel
        localChannel.onmessage = (event) => logMessage(`Receive: ${event.data}`);
        // Function Called When Channel is Opened
        localChannel.onopen = (event) => logMessage(`Channel Changed: ${event.type}`);
        // Function Called When Channel is Closed
        localChannel.onclose = (event) => logMessage(`Channel Changed: ${event.type}`);

        // Create Offer, Set Local Description and Send Offer to other users connected
        localConnection
          .createOffer()
          .then(offer => localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer))
          .then(() => {
            socket.emit('offer', socketId, localConnection.localDescription);
          });
      });

      // Receive Offer From Other Client
      socket.on('offer', (socketId, description) => {
        // Ininit peer connection
          remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(pcConfig);

        // Add all tracks from stream to peer connection
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => remoteConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

        // Send Candidtates to establish a channel communication to send stream and data
        remoteConnection.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
          candidate && socket.emit('candidate', socketId, candidate);
        };

        // Receive stream from remote client and add to remote video area
        remoteConnection.ontrack = ({ streams: [ stream ] }) => {
          remoteVideo.srcObject = stream;
        };

        // Chanel Received
        remoteConnection.ondatachannel = ({ channel }) => {
          // Store Channel
          remoteChannel = channel;

          // Function Called When Receive Message in Channel
          remoteChannel.onmessage = (event) => logMessage(`Receive: ${event.data}`);
          // Function Called When Channel is Opened
          remoteChannel.onopen = (event) => logMessage(`Channel Changed: ${event.type}`);
          // Function Called When Channel is Closed
          remoteChannel.onclose = (event) => logMessage(`Channel Changed: ${event.type}`);
        }

        // Set Local And Remote description and create answer
        remoteConnection
          .setRemoteDescription(description)
          .then(() => remoteConnection.createAnswer())
          .then(answer => remoteConnection.setLocalDescription(answer))
          .then(() => {
            socket.emit('answer', socketId, remoteConnection.localDescription);
          });
      });

      // Receive Answer to establish peer connection
      socket.on('answer', (description) => {
        localConnection.setRemoteDescription(description);
      });

      // Receive candidates and add to peer connection
      socket.on('candidate', (candidate) => {
        // GET Local or Remote Connection
        const conn = localConnection || remoteConnection;
        conn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
      });


    }
```

this is the client index.html

```
    @page
    @model IndexModel
    <h1>Hello!</h1>

    <!-- My Video and Remote Video from connection -->
    <div id="video-grid">
        <video playsinline autoplay muted id="local-video"></video>
        <video playsinline autoplay id="remote-video"></video>
    </div>

    <!-- Input to send messages -->
    <div>
        <span style="font-weight: bold">Message: </span>
        <input type="text" id="message-input" title="Message to Send!">
        <button id="message-button">Send</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Area to Print Images -->
    <div class="messages"></div>
```

What i have done is i bought a Debian Linux VPS Server where i am hosting the site under SSL so the page goes to this server and the server.js which is the nodeJS server using socket.io  is running on the same VPS Debian Linux Server which is running on port 3000.

When i run the site in the browser i get this error:

```
lling-xhr.js:206     GET https://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OU5oGC9 net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID value
```

Why do i keep getting the cert error?, i have created the cert on the server side many times, using other resources but came across the one mentioned previously.

I also configured Linux to use ssl so the browser does have a valid ssl certificate.

Its failing on this line:

```
const socket = io('https://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000');
```